# WPF Image and button referencing to same URL

Tags: wpf, image, button, hyperlink, textblock

I have a lot of logos (Image) including a text line (TextBlock) below it. When the user double clicks either on the logo or the text line, an URL should be opened (equal for logo and line). In the example below I have the current code for one logo/link combinations. But the problem I have is that I have to duplicate the URL (for both the URL in the code of buttonPcgTools_MouseDoubleClick and TextBlock). Is there a way to optimize this?

```
    <Button Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" 
            MouseDoubleClick="buttonPcgTools_MouseDoubleClick">
        <Image Stretch="Fill" 
               Source="/PcgTools;component/Help/External Links/pcgtoolssmaller.jpg" />
    </Button>
    <TextBlock Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="14,60,0,0" 
               VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="203" FontWeight="Bold">
        <Hyperlink NavigateUri=
                    "http://www.korgforums.com/forum/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=63765"
                   RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
            <TextBlock Text="PCG Tools @ KorgForums" FontSize="16" />
        </Hyperlink>
    </TextBlock>
```

Code of buttonPcgTools_MouseDoubleClick:

```
   private void buttonFaceBook_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, 
        System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ShowHyperlink("https://www.facebook.com/PcgTools");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about putting both the image and the text into the same Hyperlink? This would however be navigated by a single click on the image instead of a double click.

```
<TextBlock>
    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="..." RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
        <Image Height="50" Source="..."/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <Run>PCG Tools @ KorgForums</Run>
    </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Yes this looks much better ... I try it soon; if it works I will accept this answer as best.

Answer (score 1):

An easy fix would be to refer to a static property on a class. You can reference the string in XAML with `NavigateUri="{StaticResource res:Resources.MyURL}"` and `xmlns:res="clr-namespace:MyApp.Properties"` as a namespace declaration. In code you just access with `Resources.MyURL`. This static property could come from a standard .resx file or you could make your own static class.

Comment: Thanks, seems better than my solution, but still I have multiple references. I hoped there would be a way to have both (equal) strings or string resources in XAML and not in C# code-behind.